# I connected external HDD to windows PC, now I can't mount it on my linux rpi

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, raspberry-pi

So I have the 6TB external HDD that I use as a NAS in combination with an raspberry pi and samba. Recently I physically connected the hard disk to a windows laptop with usb cabel and transferred some files from window to the hard disk. Few day later I am trying to connect the external HDD to the raspberry pi but i something is wrong... I reinstall the OS (raspberrypi OS lite), I then run command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

But what I see is different that earlier,

```
Disk /dev/sda: 5.5 TiB, 6001175125504 bytes, 11721045167 sectors
Disk model: Backup+ Hub BK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 39B54FAE-85DF-4292-B470-D242UGTO7F

Device      Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      34      262177      262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda2  264192 11721043967 11720779776  5.5T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

This also result in not being possible to mount the drive. When I try to mount it I get this error, which I have never seen before

```
 sudo mount /dev/sda2 /media
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.19.118-v7l+/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module fuse not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.118-v7l+
ntfs-3g-mount: fuse device is missing, try 'modprobe fuse' as root
```

So my fear is that windows have now changed some formatting of the harddisk and that it no longer work with linux. If this is the case, I really hope that someone can tell me that there is a way to fix this without losing all the data on the drive 
Please help

Comment: The message says "try `modprobe fuse` as root". Well, did you? What happened?

Comment: Hi Kamil. No I didn't, and I dont understand what it means. What are the instructions to do this ?

Comment: When you use the `mount` command, explicitly specify the type of filesystem with the `-t` option.  Try `-t ntfs` and `-t vfat`.

Comment: @sawdust that worked ! Thanks a lot! `-t ntfs`

Answer (score -1):

What I would try and do is download data from the drive onto the windows computer format the drive in a format that is supported on Linux and upload the data to the drive. If you cant download data to Windows pc I would recommend downloading a drive recovery software or sending it off.
(Updated)
Try this
You may need to format the whole disk to achieve either FAT32 or NTFS filesystem to be recognised by system
You may need to assign a letter for the disk (sometimes system fails to assign one)
You may need to create a partition and set it to active

Comment: well, I can't unfortunately. my windows machine does not have 6TB storage.... :s

Comment: Ok, what’s does it say when you put the HDD in the Linux machine is there an error or does not appear?

Comment: look at updated post

Comment: i don't see anything when i plug it in. It's a headless linux that I am running so I only have Mr. Terminal who doesn't speak, only answer ;) Regarding the need to format, that is what I also read in another blog post, how over, it seems strange to me that I need to format the entire disk and loose all my data, when windows had no problem changing its format in few seconds while transferring one large file. I would have hope there would be an equally easy revert of that.

Comment: Ok, I use Linux myself so will get a VMware on my other windows and see if i can recreate the issue using old drive with a txt file on and see if i can format without losing Datq.

Comment: that would be awsome:)